# My page content is not centered in IE7. Why?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I coded and integrated a website into Wordpress, but for some reason it looks awful in Internet Explorer 7.

The content is not centered. Is there any hack for this?
All the other browsers seem to be working fine...

This is my website:
http://slavisaperisic.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the auto margin method to center the content, try to set the text alingment of the parent element to centered. This should fix the problem.